# run php file from shell script in openwrt

Tags: php, shell, openwrt

I am trying to run a php file from shell script file or terminal in open-wrt platform. I have executed php files in crontab  and those are running perfectly. i need to run a php  file without putting it into crontab.I am trying it with the following command

```
chmod 777 /www/api/*
cd /www/api
php myphp.php
```

but it showing **-ash: php: not found**

I have also try it putting the following command on top of the script

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

but it is not working. i could not figure out the problem!!!

Comment: Php it's not installd for the cli env, try using: opkg update
opkg install php5
opkg install php5-cgi

Answer (score 0):

You must install php-cli package, after you can run the script by

```
php-cli script.php
```